# Is it possible to have an action listener on a list item element and pass it as a parameter in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, actionlistener

Is it possible to set an action listener for a list item in HTML and pass what the user clicked in JavaScript?

Index.html:

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn d-flex align-items-center" type="button">
    <h3 class="fs-1 fw-bold">Set Limit</h3>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {

   // I want this to be able to get its value
   // depending on what the user clicked from the <li> tag
   var limit = 1;
});
</script>
```

I updated my code now to

Index.html:

```
<select id="dropdown">
   <option value="A" data-number="1">option1</option>
   <option value="B" data-number="2">option2</option>
   <option value="C" data-number="3">option3</option>
   <option value="D" data-number="4">option4</option>
</select>

<script>
$('#dropdown').change(function(){
   var number = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-number');
});

$(function() {
   /* I am unsure now on how to get the number variable from above and put it here in my var limit */
   var limit = ;
});

</script>
```

Comment: You're using a lot of contradictory code/words here. Your code is an unordered list with some list items. But its class is "drop-down"(?) You talk about the "value" of a list item but values are more commonly associated with [select/drop-down list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) options. Do you just want an unordered list, or do you want a select element with options that have a `value` attribute that you can select?

Comment: I want to select an element with options that have a value, I'm using bootstrap and I thought they all work the same. Is there any better approach for this?

Comment: [select](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/select/), and [list](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/list-group/) - which one do you want?

Comment: Hello, I have updated my code and choose select, I am unsure now on how to get the number variable from above and put it here in my var limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it really depends on your flow of data. Here I'm grabbing the selected value from the `select` element within the `change` handler, and passing it as an argument to a function called `main` which logs it to the console.

Note: I moved the value from the `data-number` attribute to the value (otherwise what's the point of the value...?)

```js
$('select').on('change', handleChange);

function handleChange() {
  const limit = $(this).val();
  main(limit);
}

function main(limit) {
  console.log(limit);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select class="form-select">
  <option selected disabled>Select an option</option>
  <option value="1">option1</option>
  <option value="2">option2</option>
  <option value="3">option3</option>
  <option value="4">option4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using query I suggest to use `on`

```
<script>
    var currentLimit = 1;
    $(function() {
       $("li").on("click", function ()
       {
          currentLimit = parseInt(this.innerText);
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm new to query, How will I be able to store the 1 in my variable?